# What are the advantages of using rubinius

Tags: ruby, rubinius

Could you give me some examples were is worth it use rubinius, like in this post:
http://yehudakatz.com/2009/08/31/simplifying-rails-block-helpers-with-a-side-of-rubinius/

Comment: This guy did a blog post benchmarking different versions of ruby...pretty interesting! http://andrewsblog.org/ruby-comparisons-benchmark

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hey there, I'll take a shot:

1. Fantastic backtraces
2. Super well tested via RubySpec
3. Ultra responsive dev team
4. Modern garbage collection
5. Beautiful source code, much of it in Ruby!
6. Easy to get involved (open commit bit)
7. Good performance, occasionally great, improving very quickly
8. Native threads
9. GIL elimination work in progress, excellent threaded performance in the future
10. First class Windows support work in progress

JRuby shares these benefits, except #9, because it's doesn't have a GIL and already has terrific multi-threaded performance! :-)

Comment: And how does the performance compare to use the MRI 1.9.2 (I know it's not really MRI anymore).

Comment: I would love to see a page which shows the rubyspec results and where it's lacking.